# I have an array of unequal length lists, what is quickest way to calculate the length of each

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the array `a`

```
a = np.array([
        [list(range(np.random.randint(4, 10))) for _ in range(10)],
        [list(range(np.random.randint(4, 10))) for _ in range(10)]
    ]).T

print(a)

[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

I'd expect output like this

```
[[7 6]
 [8 7]
 [9 9]
 [9 5]
 [6 8]
 [6 7]
 [5 5]
 [9 9]
 [9 6]
 [8 7]]
```

Comment: `map` and `len` come to mind

Comment: You mean quckiest as in the most CPU efficient, or fastest to impelemnt (the least lines to write)?

Comment: CPU efficient, sticking to numpy, pandas, standard library...

Comment: @piRSquared Then probably having it as a generator, would be most efficient: `mygen = (map(len, row) for row in a)`, but dont have any benchmarks to back it up.

Comment: @Marcin that's a good answer.  I've since figured out a quicker way that I'll post.  But I'd rather select an answer that isn't mine.  Can you please post that?

Comment: @piRSquared I can make anwser based on my comment if you like the sugguestion.

Comment: Here your object array is essentially a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have it most efficient, I would suggest using a generator:

```
mygen = (map(len, row) for row in a)
```

This way you dont need to compute everything at once. You do it only when you need it. But I dont have any CPU benchmarks to back it up.

Comment: I used this from your suggestion: `[[i for i in map(len, row) for row in a]`

Answer (score 1):

***method 1***
`pandas`

```
def pir1(a):
    return pd.Series(a.ravel()).str.len().values.reshape(a.shape)
```

***method 2***
`itertools`, `map`, `len`

```
def pir2(a):
    return np.array(
        [i for i in map(len, itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))]).reshape(a.shape)
```

***method 3***
@Marcin

```
def marcin(a):
    return(np.array([[i for i in map(len, row) for row in a])
```

---

***small array***

```
n, m = 10, 2
a = np.array(
    [[list(range(np.random.randint(1, 21))) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
)
```

[image]

---

***large array***

```
n, m = 1000, 20
a = np.array(
    [[list(range(np.random.randint(1, 21))) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
)
```

[image]

---

***very big array***

```
n, m = 10000, 200
a = np.array(
    [[list(range(np.random.randint(1, 21))) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
)
```

[image]